# Sim card connection?

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband

I have a Dell latitude E7240, and I inserted my SIM card (Ortel) to be able to connect to the internet.
But I don't know the steps required to configure my connection.

Comment: If the modem is recognized then you should have an option to configure a mobile connection right there in your networks dropdown menu.

Comment: If the modem isn't properly recognized, we need at least to know which one as there are some six or so different ones mentioned at Dell's website for Latitude E7240.